# How to remove double quotes & dots altogether from a file

Tags: text-processing

I have below file content from which I want to remove double quotes `"` and dot `.`:

```
Password expiration notice for beems Server
# cat pschagKK
Password expiration notice for "beems" Server.example.com
Password expiration notice for "beems" Server.example.com
Password expiration notice for "beems" Server.example.com
Password expiration notice for "goog_dev" Server.example.com
Password expiration notice for "goog_integ" Server.example.com
Password expiration notice for "noodle" Server.example.com
Password expiration notice for "noodle" Server.example.com
Password expiration notice for "pacct" Server.example.com
Password expiration notice for "pacct" Server.example.com
Password expiration notice for "pacct" Server.example.com
Password expiration notice for "pacct" Server.example.com
Password expiration notice for "pacct" Server.example.com
```

I am trying `sed` but unable to find a way to remove dots as well:

```
# cat pschagKK | sed 's/"/ /g'
Password expiration notice for  beems  Server.example.com
Password expiration notice for  beems  Server.example.com
```

Comment: `awk '{gsub(/"|\./,"")}1' file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way with `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/[".]//g' <file
```

Comment: My bad i just forgot to add , i want to remove dot and everything  after string "server".

Comment: Rest your code working like a charm Cuonglm

Comment: For Now i thoght tohave below solution , at least they are space separated now..


# sed -e 's/[".]/ /g' pschagKK


Password expiration notice for  beems  Server example com
Password expiration notice for  beems  Server example com
Password expiration notice for  beems  Server example com

Comment: cuong, +1..just curious.. is `-e` needed here? is it doing anything?

Comment: @heemayl: No, `-e` is not required here.

Answer (score 2):

Another way (and less typing) is `tr`:

```
tr -d '".' < file
```